# Silverstripe: How to allow javascript in tinymce?

Tags: tinymce, silverstripe

Admins and editors on one of my sites wants to include some javascript embeds like twitter, facebook, instagram or whatever, on pages. I thought it would be really easy to just set the extended_valid_elements to allow the script tag in the html editor of tinyMCE, but it apparently doesn't work.

I've added this to my config

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOption(
    'extended_valid_elements',
    'script[charset|defer|language|src|type|async]'
);
```

And I've checked that it's passed to the ssTinyMCEconfig variable in my dom.

So far so good. But when I try to post a simple script in to my HTML-editor, it strips it. Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than manage custom scripts through the TinyMCE editor we could add a text variable to `$db` to manage the custom scripts through a plain `TextareaField`.

The following code works for SilverStripe 3.4:

```php
class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $db = array(
        'CustomScript' => 'Text'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.CustomScript', 
            TextareaField::create('CustomScript', 'Custom Script')
                ->setRows(30)
                ->addExtraClass('code')
                ->setAttribute('spellcheck', 'false'));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Here is some custom css for the CMS to make the script input fields display the text with a monospace font.

**mysite/css/cms.css**

```css
.field.code textarea {
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    color: #000000;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

We enable the custom css in the cms with the following code in our `config.yml` file:

**mysite/_config/config.yml**

```
LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - 'mysite/css/cms.css'
```

In our `Page.ss` template in the head tag, or at the bottom of the body tag, or whether we would like the custom script, we put the following to load our custom script:

```
<% if $CustomScript %>
    $CustomScript.RAW
<% end_if %>
```

If we want site wide custom scripts we could also add this field to the Settings tab by extending our `SiteConfig`:

**mysite/code/extensions/CustomSiteConfig.php**

```php
class CustomSiteConfig extends DataExtension {

    private static $db = array(
        'CustomScript' => 'Text'
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.CustomScript',
            TextareaField::create('CustomScript', 'Custom Script')
                ->setRows(30)
                ->addExtraClass('code')
                ->setAttribute('spellcheck', 'false'));
    }
}
```

We enable this `SiteConfig` extension in our `config.yml` file:

**mysite/_config/config.yml**

```
SiteConfig:
  extensions:
     - CustomSiteConfig
```

In our `Page.ss` template in the head tag, or at the bottom of the body tag, we put the following to load our site wide custom script:

```
<% if $SiteConfig.CustomScript %>
    $SiteConfig.CustomScript.RAW
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I ended up doing something similar, just injecting it with the Requirements class.

The administrators of the site thought of it as a hard way doing something simple, though. Which I think may come from that they were used to including javascript through TinyMCE, but I think this solution will be sufficient :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around the issue for Twitter embed by simply including the relevant script links in my header. This embedded the twitter-tweet `blockquote` code that I pasted into TimyMCE.

Comment: Yep, that would be a quick fix, but it kind of defeats the purpose of letting admins injecting javascript themselves :-)

Thanks for the suggestion anyways.